# Exporting Matlab data to excel, 2003 2010

Tags: excel, matlab

I am attempting to export data from Matlab to excel, I know to do this you use `xlswrite` and I have managed to  get this to work but when I increase the number of rows/lines of data I get the following error `Excel returned: Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC.` I know that this error is because I am exceeding the limits of excel 2003 but I am trying to export my data to excel 2010 and my data size is not exceeding the limits of excel 2010. Matlab saves the data as a 97-2003 Worksheet which explains why I am confined to the limits of 2003. Is there a way to save the data as a 2010 worksheet so I can write all of my data to excel?
Part of my code:

```
xlswrite(test_1,Data_1,1)
xlswrite(test_1,Data_2,2)
xlswrite(test_1,Data_3,3)
```

Data_1 & 2 & 3  are all 3 columns by any number of rows defined by the user

Comment: What is the value `test_1`? Try make the file extension `.xlsx` not `.xls`?

Comment: test_1 is the name of the file, I will give the `.xlsx` a go, thanks

Comment: Thanks @Dan it worked a treat if i set the filename to `'test_1.xlsx'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel 2003 files have the `.xls` extension. For a long time now (like 2009 or 2007) Matlab's `xlswrite` has supported the new 2007 `.xlsx` format so long as your files name specifies this. So if your file name was `"test_1.xls"` then it will save as an `.xls` file i.e. 2003. So to get the new format all you have to do is name it `"test_1.xlsx"`.

Comment: Initially I didn't put `.xls` or `.xlsx` extension on my file name just `test_1`, so Matlab as default puts the `xls` extension at the end of the file name.